# How to launch .apk for installation on Button Click?

Tags: android, button, installation, apk

How to launch .apk for installation on Button Click ?

```
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("link"));
               Intent launchBr = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uriUrl);
                 startActivity(launchBr);

                   /// i want to launch apk file to install                     
               }
```

Comment: how about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: Thanks. working fine.